# Как сделать выезжающий/заезжающий элемент?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, как сделать выезжающий/заезжающий элемент, как показано на рисунке(анимация появления/скрытия не обязательна). По нажатию на кнопку справа должна появиться область, при повторном нажатии на кнопку она должна скрыться. 
Скрытие должно происходить только(!) по нажатию на кнопку. Я пытался быдлокодить, задавая нулевую высоту у Layout'ов, но ничего хорошего из этого не вышло. Может есть более изящные решения.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
              android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/STANDART_GRAY"
        >

    <View
            android:id="@+id/leftLine"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:background="@color/STOPS_COLOR"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />
    <!--icon-->
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutIcon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_list"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftLine"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"

                />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--names-->
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutNames"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutIcon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutMore"
            android:background="@color/STANDART_GRAY"


            >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_NAME_1"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
                android:textColor="@color/COLOR_NAME_2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text=""

                />


    </RelativeLayout>





    <!--more-->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMore"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/STANDART_GRAY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"

            >

        <View
                android:id="@+id/rightLine"
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/vertical_divider"

                />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/STANDART_GRAY"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"

                android:paddingRight="25dp"

                android:text=">>"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hideble"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layoutIcon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutMore"
            android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalLine"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutNames"
            android:background="@color/STANDART_GRAY"
            />

 <View
     android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@color/vertical_divider"

     />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) - такие вещи делаются через него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать

```
//element - элемент, который выезжает, должен наследоваться от View
//Для скрытия:
element.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//Для возвращения:
element.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

А боковым элементам можно задать "match_parent" по высоте.

Comment: да, я об этом знаю, извиняюсь, я не совсем точно описал проблему, сейчас я обновил в вопросе изображения.Изменение размера всего элемента должно как то сказываться на боковых. Они должны растянуться и сжаться. Показан один элемент ListView, после и до нажатия

Comment: Я бы сделала так. Весь элемент - LinearLayout горизонтальный, по высоте wrap_content. Часть с элементами -  LinearLayout вертикальный, по высоте тоже самое. Часть с кнопкой -  по высоте match_parent. По ширине как душе угодно. Ну это так, навскидку.

Comment: Я привел пример своей разметки, но она ведет себя совсем неадекватно
потому что левая(зеленая) полоса пропадает совсем, а правая(серая) очень маленькая по высоте.

Answer (score 0):

это называется ExpandableListView - стандартный контролл в разметке андроида, бог пейна ) или в твоем случае больше подойдет просто Spinner - тоже стандартный виджет

Comment: обновил картинку, должно быть так, я думал уже об  ExpandableListView и Spinner, но я не придумал как реализовать вот то, что я показал.
Элементы боковые должны реагировать на изменение размеров всего элемента(это один из элементов ListView)

Comment: > бог пейна ) 

@Gorets, а вы, судя по всему, бог английского языка